# opening a website on a specific webbrowser element

Tags: powershell, winforms

I have several webbrowser elements in a form. Every webbrowser has a combobox where some URLs are stored in there. By selecting a website the content shall be shown in the bounded webbrowser element. My code works well so far, but after selection of a website from a combo box it is shown in all webbrowser elements.

```
$cbo1.datasource=$datatable
$cbo2.datasource=$datatable
...
$cbo1.Add_SelectedIndexChanged({ $web1.url=$cbo1.SelectedItem["webURL"]})
$cbo2.Add_SelectedIndexChanged({ $web2.url=$cbo2.SelectedItem["webURL"]})
...
```

In the starting part of the form the websites (all different) get's set by $web.url="http..." which works fine.
What do I have to change that I can load an url to a specific webbrowser element?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the datasource. Every combobox needs it's own datasource. If the selected item gets changed on one datasource all comboboxes gets updated.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).